# File explorer does not auto-refresh after file operations after Windows Update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I recently updated Windows 10 to the latest 20H2 update (after having skipped the past 2 or 3), and noticed some time after that that file operations in any of my Explorer windows were not being actively being reflected after the change: renames, deletions, copies, moves, etc. The only way to get these changes to appear has been to either click out and back in to the folder, or to hit F5.

I've been scouring the internet for the past two days trying to find a solution to this problem, and while it seems like it's been an issue going back the past decade now, there haven't really been any recent results on this, and none of the older suggestions I've found have worked: I've tried registry edits, I've tried resetting folder defaults, I've tried system scans, and even went as far as resetting Windows entirely (while keeping my files). This last hammer of a step actually did briefly solve the issue, but it came back after I re-installed my apps and rebooted.

Would really appreciate some ideas here!

Edit: I tried creating new user accounts to locate the problem, but it doesn't seem consistent, so either it's a non-deterministic bug, or it just starts to happen after some period of time has passed.

Comment: Are you talking about file operations on a local NTFS disc, or on a (mounted) network drive?

Comment: Local! I don't have any network drives on this machine

Comment: So the problem only resurfaced after you reinstalled the software that was installed.  When you first noticed this problem what applications were recently updated?

Comment: Seems like this is a Windows specific bug. I've done a bunch more testing and created new user accounts (that still have the same installed software), and it'll work for a bit, even after reboots, then randomly stop working later. My old account has actually started sporadically working again, but still breaks on occasion.

Comment: I have the same issue with windows 10 (10.0.19045 Build 19045) on Lenovo Legion. The bug is not predictable and occurs on local drive. @Johnny could you please post some details on the previous solution you tried ?

Comment: @mxdsp I didn't really try anything that worked consistently, unfortunately. It just seemed to stop happening as much at some point: I still occasionally see this with temp download files not getting refreshed after download completion, but the other file operations stopped being an issue

Comment: Have you been using some kind of "optimisation utility" like CleanUp, TunesUp, WinPrivacy, ? I suspect that one of them might have change some hidden setting (maybe cache, or display refresh setting) on my system.

Comment: @mxdsp sorry, haven't checked this account in a while. I did not have anything like that, no. The only file-related software I ran was Avira and Backblaze, but I don't think any of those would have caused it. I'm on Win11 now and still very rarely notice this issue with the temp downloads, but hasn't happened otherwise